# How to update page after filling the blank with javascipt commands in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autofill

I can fill a blank of an HTML page in Chrome console with javascript command like :

```
document.getElementById("blankID").value = 1;
```

This code works fine however, it does not update the page.

If I do the same thing manually, when I place the cursor on the same place and type "1" and click somewhere else or press enter, the page is updated (not reloaded). I want to do the same thing using javascript. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description it seems that you did two things to trigger this behavior:

- change the value of some field
- blurring out from it

Your Javascript sets the value of a field, for the purpose of this answer I will suppose that you are setting the correct field correctly. Then, you need to focus on another element. So, let's suppose you get an element (via a selector or something), called `element` that differs from the one whose value you have changed. You can try

```
element.focus();
```

I'm writing this answer without having an example of your code or a reproducible example. Let me know if it works for you. If not, then please provide more information to your question.

EDIT

This script worked for me at your example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("calcSearchTerm");
element.value = 3;
calcSearch();
```

This is what led me to the solution:

[image]

Look at the `onkeyup` attribute, which is a handler for the keyup event. Since we programmatically change the value, there is no keyup being triggered. Yet, we know what function it should induce, so we do not need to trigger the event programmatically, instead, we can just call the function it would otherwise call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could not make it work and I have an example that you can reproduce the issue. Here is the webpage to try:https://www.calculator.net/

when you type 3 in the search bar, the text appears as " No calculator matches "3".
But when you do it with js like :
 
```
let elem = document.getElementById("calcSearchTerm");
elem.value =3;
let otherelem = document.getElementById("scirdsettingr");
otherelem.focus();
```

It does not appear. Does it work for reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @controlsHeaven yes, I can look into it, but on long-term links to problems tend to be disfavored on SO, because links become nonfunctional over time. So I'm looking into it, but later you might want to convert this into an in-site reference

Comment: You are right, I will keep this in mind, thanks for making me aware of it !

Comment: @controlsHeaven edited my answer with a script that was successfully tested at your page in the console.

Comment: perfect! Though I did not do the same thing for my case, I did a similar thing when I looked into "onBlur" function and called it, it worked out. Many Thanks!